No security protocol defined for listener
I have this error after starting Kafka with docker-compose start: No security protocol defined for listener
This is my docker-composer.yaml
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
 
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    volumes:
      - ./data/zookeeper_data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - ./data/zookeeper_log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log      

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 9094:9094
    volumes:
      - ./data/kafka1/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
      - ./data/kafka1/etc:/etc/kafka
    environment:
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: yes
      KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT: no
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9094
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT

if I delete all the folders inside data that contain all the volumes kafka starts fine.
What would it be the problem ?


Why do you need to use Zookeeper mode? 2) What if you use the official Apache Kafka docker image?


I did it but I didn't find all the utilities to manage topics, produce or consume. For example: bin/kafka-topics.sh

Those scripts are there... Did you try find / -name kafka-topics.sh ?

yes I used apache/kafka:latest and I did find and in /bin it doesn't exists

It's not in /bin. It's in /opt/kafka/bin... https://stackoverflow.com/a/78316400/2308683

Yes, I found it. I would like to to init a new topic in docker-compose with apache/kafka, what is the way to do that in confluentic we have confluentinc/cp-kafka

Both images work the exact same with that regard. You can use an "init container" with any Kafka image that starts after the broker is healthy. What issues are you having?

confluentinc/cp-kafka allowed me to create a new topic inside the docker-compose.yml. What is the related way to implement it in apache/kafka.

As mentioned, it works the exact same way. Neither image have an environment variable for this, so you must write a script. Using a container that starts after the broker, then terminates is an industry accepted solution.
